# Saving the bits that are shifted off in a left-shift (SHL)

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, bit-shift, x86-16

Consider the following Intel 8086 Assembly program:

CX holds non-zero value.

```
L: ADD AX, AX
   ADC DX, 0
   LOOP L
```

I was asked to understand the above code and rewrite it for better efficiency.
As far as I could understand:

1. It saves the value of 2^CX * AX into AX
2. Counts the number of times the carry flag was set to 1 in the process and saves it in DX.

Assuming this is correct, I thought a better code would SHL the value in AX, CX times. 
`SHL AX, CX`
However, I couldn't think of a way to sum the carry bits in the process. (or count the number of '1' bits in the CX most significant bits of the original AX.)

Any guidance and assistance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: See `SHLD` or, if not available, synthesize it yourself.

Comment: `SHL` puts the shifted-off bit into carry (CF), so you could still use `ADC reg, 0` to accumulate that bit. But `SHL reg, cl` is *not* going to be fast on the 8086, so this won't be an optimization. Or at least not a very good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of how the current code works is essentially correct. Just to make sure we understand it, let's step through a sample execution. Normally, this kind of thing would be done with a debugger at hand, but all we *really* need here is our head and a calculator that can display binary values.

Let's say that `AX` is 55312 (choosing a large initial value allows us to see the effect of a carry immediately). `CX` will be 4, and of course `DX` is pre-zeroed.

- Iteration 1: `55312 + 55312` overflows the range of a 16-bit value, so the carry bit is set, and `AX` is now 45088. Because carry was set, `DX` = 1. `CX` is decremented to 3.
- Iteration 2: `45088 + 45088` overflows again, so the carry bit is set, and `AX` is now 24640.
  `DX` = 2; `CX` = 2.
- Iteration 3: `24640 + 24640` does not overflow, so the carry bit is *not* set, and `AX` is now 49280.
  `DX` = 2; `CX` = 1.
- Iteration 4: `49280 + 4928` overflows, so the carry bit is set, and `AX` is now 33024.
  `DX` = 3; `CX` = 0.

So, when we finish, `DX` is 3. If we look at the binary representation of the starting value:

```
1101 1000  0001 0000
↑                  ↑
bit 15             bit 0
```

you can see confirmation of your intuition: the number of set (1) bits in the upper 4 (`CX`) bits of this value is 3, which is equal to `DX`.

These types of bit-level observations, which lead to clever, bit-twiddling tricks, are the key to most optimization break-throughs, and you already spotted this one by thinking through what the code you have actually does, which is very good.

Collecting our thoughts, let's write out the algorithm explicitly, assuming that `AX` is the input value and `CX` contains the number of iterations:

- Isolate the upper `CX` bits in `AX`, discarding the rest.
- Count the number of set bits in `AX`.

If we were targeting a modern processor—Intel Nehalem, AMD Barcelona, and newer—it would be a simple matter of right-shifting using `SHR`, and then using the `POPCNT` instruction to count the number of set bits in the desired range. For example:

```
; AX == input value
; CX == number of iterations

neg    cx
add    cx, 16     ; cx = 16 - cx

shr    ax, cl     ; ax = ax << cx

popcnt ax, ax     ; ax = # of 1 bits in ax
```

This is going to be *fast*. There's no branching/looping; just 4 simple instructions. You're looking at only a handful of cycles in execution time, with no possibility for a branch misprediction.

But what if you are targeting an older CPU where the `POPCNT` instruction doesn't exist? Well, you'll need to emulate it. There are a variety of fast ways to implement a population count/Hamming weight algorithm. On a Pentium or later, the fastest way would be something like:

```
; AX == input value
; CX == number of iterations

neg  cx
add  cx, 16     ; cx = 16 - cx

shr  ax, cl     ; ax = ax << cx

; emulate popcnt
mov  dx, ax
shr  dx, 1
and  dx, 21845
sub  ax, dx
mov  cx, ax
and  ax, 13107
shr  cx, 2
and  cx, 13107
add  cx, ax
mov  dx, cx
shr  dx, 4
add  dx, cx
and  dx, 3855
mov  ax, dx
shr  ax, 8
add  ax, dx
and  ax, 63
```

This is a 16-bit adaptation of [this method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel), which parallelizes the bit count using a series of shifts, additions, and masks. These are all simple instructions, and it's still branchless, so it's pretty darn fast on most processors…but not the 8088/8086! On those old dinosaurs, even simple instructions like these take multiple cycles to execute, and worse, they all have to be *decoded*, so the slow memory access speeds tend to slow things down. If you really want to optimize this for an 8088/8086, you need to implement the population-count algorithm using a look-up table. And, on these processors, the oft-forgotten 1-byte `XLAT` instruction is by far the fastest way to look up a value in a table:

```
LUT DB   0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,7,6,7,7,8
```

```
; AX == input value
; CX == number of iterations

neg  cx
add  cx, 16            ; cx = 16 - cx

shr  ax, cl            ; ax = ax << cx

; emulate popcnt using LUT
mov  bx, OFFSET LUT
xlat                   ; equivalent to: mov al, [bx + al]
xchg al, ah
xlat                   ; equivalent to: mov al, [bx + al]
add  al, ah
xor  ah, ah
```

This costs you 256 bytes to store the look-up table (LUT) in your code, but it is *definitely* faster in execution speed on the 8088/8086 than doing all of that arithmetic. We can get an approximate estimate of the execution speed by counting cycles:

```
neg  cx               ; 3         cycles
add  cx, 16           ; 4         cycles
shr  ax, cl           ; 8+(4*CL)  cycles
mov  bx, OFFSET LUT   ; 4         cycles
xlat                  ; 11        cycles
xchg al, ah           ; 4         cycles
xlat                  ; 11        cycles
add  al, ah           ; 3         cycles
xor  ah, ah           ; 3         cycles
                      ;-----------------
                      ; 51+(4*CL) cycles
```

Notice that the slow instruction here is the right-shift. It takes a fixed 8 cycles, plus 4 additional cycles for each bit that is shifted (*i.e.*, the shift count, which is in `CL`). Unfortunately, there isn't much we can do about that. This means we have a best-case performance of about 50 cycles, with a worst case performance that is still under 120 cycles.

Compare that to your original code:

```
   xor  dx, dx        ; 3 cycles
L: add  ax, ax        ; 3 cycles
   adc  dx, 0         ; 4 cycles
   loop L             ; taken: 17 cycles; not-taken: 5 cycles
                      ;---------------------------------------
                      ; 8+(24*CL) cycles
```

Here, the approximate number of cycles depends on `CX` (the loop count), since that determines the number of times that the branch is taken. So, in the best case, this code takes around 32 cycles; in the worst case, it takes somewhere shy of 400 cycles.

I want to reiterate that cycle-counting is not exact, even on a simple chip like the 8086, but it does give us a reasonable way of estimating performance. Your original code does have a slightly better *best-case* performance (in cases where `CX` is small), but our optimized, bit-counting, LUT-based approach has a much better *worst-case* performance, and more importantly, it *scales better*. You can see this clearly in the following graphical comparison of the two approaches:

[image: Graph showing relative performance of the two approaches (using estimated cycle counts)]

As long as `CX` is small, your original code is a reasonable implementation. But as `CX` gets larger, the routine gets *exponentially* slower and slower because of all those `LOOP`s. Our LUT-based approach has a greater *overhead* (and that's not even counting the bloat that the LUT adds to the binary), but really begins to pay off as `CX` gets larger. **In conclusion, we've traded increased code size for execution speed**, a common optimization trade-off.

Now, I need to come clean. I've been surreptitiously assuming this whole time that `CX` will never be greater than 16. If `CX` is greater than 16, all of the "optimized" code that I've been showing you won't work, because the `SHR` instruction will try to shift out too many bits. If you need to handle `CX` > 16, then you need to tweak the code so that it *clamps* `CX` to be less-than-or-equal-to 16. That means either a conditional branch or a series of clever bit-twiddling instructions, either of which increase the complexity of the code and increase its cycle count. In other words, this will increase the *baseline overhead* of the "optimized" approach, but this approach will continue to *scale* better than your original approach. Graphically, the red line will translate upwards.

(Your original code doesn't need any modifications—it handles `CX` values up to 65,535 without any additional penalty, because it just keeps `LOOP`ing. But as we've already seen, a significant performance penalty is paid for each of those `LOOP`s.)

The "tweaked" code would look something like this:

```
    LUT DB   0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,6,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,4,5,5,6,5,6,6,7,5,6,6,7,6,7,7,8
```

```
    ; AX == input value
    ; CX == number of iterations

    mov  bx, 16                          ; 4 cycles
    cmp  cx, bx        ; cx < 16?        ; 3 cycles
    jae  SkipShift                       ; 4 cycles (fall-through); 16 cycles (branch)
    sub  bx, cx                          ; 3 cycles
    mov  cx, bx        ; cx  -= 16       ; 2 cycles
    shr  ax, cl        ; ax <<= cx       ; 8+(4*CL) cycles
SkipShift:
    mov  bx, OFFSET LUT                  ; 4 cycles
    xlat                                 ; 11 cycles
    xchg al, ah                          ; 4 cycles
    xlat                                 ; 11 cycles
    add  al, ah                          ; 3 cycles
    xor  ah, ah                          ; 3 cycles
```

You'll pay a penalty of 16 cycles if this `JAE` is taken, but we're able to skip the subtraction and shift in that case, which makes up for those lost cycles. If the `JAE` is not taken, and execution just fall through, we only lost 4 cycles. Overall, the best-case performance is around 60 cycles, while the worst-case performance is about twice as slow.

Comment: I am indeed working under the assumption of CX < 16.
One could not explain this better!!! Thank you very much Cody

Answer (score 0):

With your non-zero cl assumption this instruction pair would be equivalent:

```
   shld  dx,ax,cl
   shl   ax,cl
```

Comment: Paul, if I am not mistaken the first instruction will not accumulate the carry bits. Would it? (i.e consider '101' to be the shifted bits, I need DX to be 2 and not 101)

Comment: I'm not sure how important it is, but `shld` is a 80386 instruction and OP wrote 8086

Comment: @Zoltan apologies... I misread the question, and thought I saw **ADC DX,DX**.  My answer is wrong (not equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `shld` (for example because your code must run on 80286 or if you want to use the same code on a non-x86 CPU) you can do the following pseudo-code:

```
if CX < 16
    DX = AX SHR (16 - CX)
    AX = AX SHL 16
else
    if CX < 32
        DX = AX SHL (CX - 16)
    else
        DX = 0
    endif
    AX = 0
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

After any variation as posted in the other answers that puts the upper bits of a shifted AX into DX, you'll need some variation of a popcnt (counts the number of 1 bits) for DX. The code to do this is somewhat lengthy, an example for 32 bit mode is shown below. For a true 8086, it would probably better to use a 256 byte table that converts an index into the number of 1 bits in the index with a sequence like:

```
        xor     bx,bx          
        mov     bl,dl                   ;bl = lower bits
        mov     dl,table[bx]            ;dl = lower # bits set
        mov     bl,dh                   ;bl = upper bits
        add     dl,table[bx]            ;dl = total # bits set
;       ...
        xor     dh,dh                   ;optional, clear upper bits dx
```

32 bit popcnt of edi example code:

```
        mov     edx,edi                 ;edx = edi
        shr     edx,1                   ;mov upr 2 bit field bits to lwr
        and     edx,055555555h          ; and mask them
        sub     edi,edx                 ;edi = 2 bit field counts
                                        ; 0->0, 1->1, 2->1, 3->1
        mov     eax,edi
        shr     edi,02h                 ;mov upr 2 bit field counts to lwr
        and     eax,033333333h          ;eax = lwr 2 bit field counts
        and     edi,033333333h          ;edx = upr 2 bit field counts
        add     edi,eax                 ;edi = 4 bit field counts
        mov     eax,edi
        shr     eax,04h                 ;mov upr 4 bit field counts to lwr
        add     eax,edi                 ;eax = 8 bit field counts
        and     eax,00f0f0f0fh          ; after the and
        imul    eax,eax,01010101h       ;eax bit 24->28 = bit count
        shr     eax,018h                ;eax bit 0->4 = bit count
```